# how can I store path of an xml in sqlite db in android and retrieve it by displaying that xml?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have been working on a SQLite database and I need to store the path of an XML layout in a SQLite database. I need to access it in an Android application. Can anyone provide me an example? Thank you

Comment: Ohh.. you have problem, what you have tried and you get this problem ?

Comment: hey I jst want to display my xml layout by accessing its name/path from sqlite db....nw u got it??

Comment: if I store name of activity in sqlite db and accessed it in a string...will i b able to intent that acivity through that string
eg: -
String s = "HomeActivity";
Intent in = new Intent(this,s.class);// this is giving error

I wanna do something like that!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to store a path? Like a String? Read about SharedPreferences. I don't know if is good practice.

Comment: shared preference is good when u wanna store string whn u navigate btwn 2 activities ....here m talkin abt sqlite db....

Comment: If you kill your activity, and startup it again, your sharedpreferences will be load.

Comment: hey man u r not gettin my problm m nt talkin abt sahred preferences m talking abt retrieving xml path/name from sqlite database and displaying it